# validation error in jsf

Tags: validation, jsf, selectonemenu

I have a probleme in SelectOneMenu in my accueil.jsf page

**xhtml page:**

```
<h:outputText value="Code type opération : " />
<h:selectOneMenu id="op" value="#{mainController.operation}">                       
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choisir Code Opération "
        itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{mainController.listeTypeOperations}" />
    <f:converter converterId="TypopConverter" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

**Converter class:**

```
public class TypOpConverter implements Converter {
    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, 
                              UIComponent component, 
                              String value) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = 
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-web.xml");
        BanqueService banqueService = 
            (BanqueService)context.getBean("banqueService");
        TypeOperation typop;
        if (value == null) {
            typop = null;
        } else {
            Long id = new Long(value);

            typop = banqueService.getTypeOperationParId(id);
            if (typop == null) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return typop;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext,
                              UIComponent component,
                              Object value) { 
        if (value == null) {
            return "";
        }
        if (value instanceof String) {
            return (String) value;
        }
        return String.valueOf(((TypeOperation) value).getId());
    }
}
```

**My managed Bean and Controller**

```
@ManagedBean(name="mainController")
@ViewScoped
public class MainController implements Serializable{

private TypeOperation operation;
// get and set

public List<TypeOperation>  getListeTypeOperations(){.....}
```

The converter run and i did some print to show the string and object but the selected value can't be stored into `#{mainController.operation}` i think

the error:

```
j_idt7:op: Validation Error: Value is not valid
```

Comment: your selectItems should be like `<f:selectItems value="#{mainController.listeTypeOperations}" var="type" itemValue="#{type}" itemLabel="#{item.someProperty}"/>`

Comment: @ElSam i did not understand what should i put in var, itemValue, itemLabel. Can u tell me exactly ?

Comment: it's just a variable name to iterate the list, what you should modify is the `itemLabel="#{type.someProperty}"` put some string property like `itemLabel="#{type.name}"`

Comment: think of it like a forEach loop , `for(TypeOperation type : listeTypeOperations ) {System.out.print(type.name);}`

Comment: Next time when you get an error, use it as [search keyword](https://www.google.com/search?q=Validation+Error%3A+Value+is+not+valid).

Comment: SOLVED. I had to override equals() and hashcode() in the model class

Comment: right click ---> source generate override and hashcode by id